# Pip-installed packages, what do they physically point to? (for use with IronPython in C#)

Tags: c#, python, pip, ironpython

This is in the context of Windows 10.

I am working on a C# application that will start a python app that does something. This python app is normally installed with Pip (pip install someAppName). The IronPython library expects a full path to a .py file to be able to execute it.

How do I know what a pip-installed application points to? From poking around, I can see this pip-installed app has a folder that resides in /site-packages. However it is not clear to me what in there gets called when I start "someAppName" from the command line. "someAppName" is the name of the folder itself, where within is a bunch of .py files so I have no idea which one is the actual starting point.

Is there a better way to do this? My goal is to package a whole "pre-installed" python application with my c# app and call/start it with IronPython.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1):

`…/site-packages/` directory is for *library* files. When you install an application there have to be a script (or scripts) installed to `…/Scripts/`.